# Firebase storage download trouble in iOS device (Unity)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-storage

I met unknown trouble trying to setup firebase storage for iOS. I can't download even 1 file in device, but it runs perfectly in Editor. 
I am using `reference.GetFileAsync()` method. Firstly I assumed that I made some wrong package setup or some other silly mistake, but I checked it many-many times. Each Quickstart project [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/blob/master/storage/testapp/Assets/TestApp/UIHandler.cs) works well on my end. My current project settings and firebase storage settings are identical to provided test examples I run in iOS device successfully.

Here is a xCode output trying to download the file. That is looped and contains only that info: [codeshare](https://codeshare.io/5gL9wY) 
Any of logs googling doesn't give me any solution or even idea.

Please, give me some thoughts where to search the problem.. I am totally confused.
I am using MacOSx, Unity 5.5.0/5.5.1, latest Firebase Unity SDK (v1.1.2)

Comment: Need a minimal working repro for a problem like this. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, spent 2 days already to figure out the trouble and didn't pay attention to that case after that.
Updated

Comment: Steps to reproduce:
 1. use storage quickstart sample
 2. switch Api Compatibility Level in player settings to .NET 2.0 (as firebase database required)
 3. try to download any file from the storage

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that firebase database package automatically changed from .NET Subset to .NET option. Changing back solved the problem. But anyway, that means we can't use firebase storage + database in same iOS project in Unity.. That's bad

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Developer here.  I'm sorry you encountered this error and I can confirm this was a regression from our initial build in January.  This issue has since been resolved in the latest version of Firebase Storage for Unity (3.0.0.0) released for general availability for mobile at GDC.

The latest version will work with the full .Net SDK which is also required for the realtime database in Unity.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have updated to latest SDK version and now that works fine. In my app I use only firebase storage without realtime SDK, but even importing storage package to Unity I have noticed about changing API compatibility to full .NET 2.0. That will raise app size and I can afford it. 
Can I still use .NET 2.0 Subset for using Storage and Authentication functionality?

Comment: if you turn on byte stripping, does that reduce the size to something manageable?

Comment: Working in iOS only IL2CPP is reasonable to use. So there is no option to select stripping. We just compare app size of Full .NET/.NET Subset, and that increases for 15mb! That's too much for us.